# DIV content shows on page instead of JQuery Dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following DIV markup:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Membership Renewal">
Your membership is going to expire.
</div>
```

I have the following javascript to execute the JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showjQueryDialog() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    //alert("Time to renew Membership!");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: { "Renew Membership": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
    });
});
</script>
```

I have an asp:Button  which is inside a control and the control is on a master page.  The first thing I notice is that when the page is loaded, the div is displayed and then disappears when the page is done loading.  When I click the button it executes the following:

```
if (timeSpan.Days >= 30)
{
//Show JQuery Dialog Here
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "showExpiration",    
"showjQueryDialog()", true);
}
```

When I click the button, instead of a dialog popping up, the content of the div just becomes visible.

Comment: Can you show the output of the ScripManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock for us? I have a hunch it's just outputting javascript directly on the page and firing before the $(document).ready.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you have two related issues here.

The reason that the DIV is showing when you first load is because you haven't yet told it not to. The jQuery script that makes the DIV behave as a dialog doesn't run until the HTML DOM is loaded, and until then it will not hide the DIV. A simple solution is to hide the DIV by default using CSS.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Membership Renewal" style="display:none;">
Your membership is going to expire.
</div>
```

The button click problem is related: `RegisterClientScriptBlock` will output a script that runs as soon as it is encountered, so the jQuery code that turns it into a dialog hasn't had a chance to run yet. In order to give it a chance to do so, you can change the C# code to use `RegisterStartupScript`, which will delay execution of `showjQueryDialog()` until the page has finished loading and the jQuery code has had a chance to make the DIV into a dialog.

```
if (timeSpan.Days >= 30)
{
  //Show JQuery Dialog Here
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), 
        "showExpiration", "showjQueryDialog()", true);
}
```

Comment: I changed the div display to none and that hides the div and I changed the code to use RegisterStartupScript, but the dialog is not showing up now.

Comment: What happens if you change the script, but leave out the display:none?

Comment: i've never had luck with putting style="display:none;" on the actual element, always seems that jquery can't modify the display of it if specified that way.

Comment: @John - I wasn't sure if that was just me, or if it was universal. Using a style declaration is definitely the way to go in that case.

Comment: I removed the style="display:none", but kept the RegisterStartupScript and it displays the content of the div directly on the page, not a dialog.

Comment: It sounds like you may not have the jQuery Dialog files all in place, then. I would check to see that all required JS, CSS, and image files are in place. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7/Dialog should tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 19):

I know this is old now. However, Set your class to the jQuery UI built in ui-helper-hidden.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Membership Renewal" class="ui-helper-hidden"> 
    Your membership is going to expire. 
</div>
```

This will resolve your div's unwanted cameo behaviour.

Comment: So what is the mechanism by which `class="ui-helper-hidden"` helps? Do I need some sort of corresponding CSS, or does JS take care of it?

Comment: jQuery takes care of it when you use a jQuery css file. All of the jquery themeroller css files have this class.  for example http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css more at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are specifying the correct doctype at the top of your page, this seems to be the cause of some issues that i've seen.

edit:

also, to keep it from flashing at the beginning you can have something like

```
#debug { display: none; }
```

somewhere before the element (most likely your stylesheet or in the head).

another thing that might help is if you put set:

```
OnClientClick="showjQueryDialog(); return false;";
```

in the page load or similar, that way you wont need a postback (asynchronous or otherwise).

Comment: There is no doctype in the control, but the one in the master page is:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: could you possibly try <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> for your doctype?

Comment: I would second the idea to use OnClientClick if possible.

Comment: The problem with OnClientClick is that I only want to display the dialog if the user's expiration date is <= 30 days.

Comment: you could add the OnClientClick in the codebehind if that condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not showing is because the document probably hasn't loaded yet.  and document.ready hasn't been called, so dialog("open") is getting called before dialog({options}); so to fix this just add the code to in a doc.ready call.

Also, your only loading the dialog once, so you don't really need to initialize it as autoOpen:false,  use the display:none then show it as John Boker said

```
function showjQueryDialog() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: { "Renew Membership": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } });
    $("#dialog").show();  // sets display:block;
    //alert("Time to renew Membership!");
  });
}

<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
  <!--..-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the display:none issue nailed me (I think again), this is very helpful.